# Synology /bin/sh: command not found

Tags: linux, path, synology

My Synology NAS just upgraded and a lot of things have broken.

My cronjob that calls Python3 keeps saying `/bin/sh: python3: command not found` but `/bin/sh` exists and I am able to call `Python3` from the commandline.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: python3 != Python3 ? Not sure about how cronjob get the PATH env var but it might have something to do with it (and where `python3`/`Python3` is)

Comment: Sorry that was just a case error. They are both `python3`. I had to manually add path of python3 to my profile

Comment: You mean some profile in your $HOME? Then I suppose you need to at least add it to some system-wide one (e.g. `/etc/profile`?)

Comment: It already is in `/etc/profile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe cron runs without the benefit of the path being defined.

Use the full path to python3 as well as the script you're executing and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to @trel's solution is to either add the `PATH` variable at top of  `crontab` file

```
PATH=$PATH:/volume1/@appstore/python3/bin
```

or by adding `source /path/to/profile && [Rest of cronjob command here]`

In my case for Synology, my profile was `/etc/profile`